# best server side framework for bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm really interested in bootstrap, and wondered if there is a really good match with a server side technology, i.e. rails or Php with a particular framework, for creating a data driven website.

It maybe subjective, *but* there is precious little information out there on this,

thanks.

Comment: Choosing a server side framework because it plays well with a CSS framework like Bootstrap, it's not reasonable in my opinion.

Comment: no need to downvote, im asking for advice on a good fit, good support, working examples. i know it will work with any backend.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, in my opinion it doesn't deserve downvotes, but I repeat you the same, they are different things. I have worked with Bootstrap in Rails, Flask and Struts2 and I haven't had any difficulties integrating Bootstrap in them. Your choice has to be something more related with what language and framework you feel more confortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like the "best server side framework" for Twitter Bootstrap. You can use it with any Framework you like. I prefer using Ruby on Rails. There are gems for using twitter bootstrap in Rails like https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass (SASS) or https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails (LESS).

I am also using https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form for generating form which plays very nice with Twitter Bootstrap when it comes to rendering validation errors.

There is also a free railscast on how to use Twitter Bootstrap with Ruby on Rails: http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics

Comment: thanks, i looked into that. The Play framework also looks good.